# How to interpret this git graph?

Tags: git, github

I have this below git graph. I don't know how to read/interpret this.
For Example: the pink line stands alone. I don't know why and is it just fine
[image]

Comment: The pink line does not stand alone. Clearly, it originates from the commit "...First Commit" that is common to both branches. This common commit cannot be blue and pink at the same time; the visualizer has to pick a color.

Answer (score 0):

The pink line is a new branch that you created from the main branch. Maybe you makes new commits in pink branch

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).